# load the current visible recyclerView's itemView's image first than others

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

i have imageview  in my recyclerView and i want to load firstly that image who's itemView is currently Visible in the RecyclerView than any other images (same as instagram )

this is how am loading images

recyclerView's onBindViewHolder :

```
CarouselAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CarouselAdapter(getContext(), myImageUrl , itemViewposition);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

here's my  CarouselAdapter Class:

```
public class CarouselAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private String[] mResources;
private  int mindex;
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;
ImageView imageView;


ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public CarouselAdapter(Context context, String[] resources, int index) {


    mContext = context;
    mResources = resources;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mindex = index;



     defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
             .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_lock)
             .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
             .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
             .cacheOnDisk(true)
             .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
             .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
             .build();


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_imgview, container, false);

    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);


    if (mResources[position] == null ){

        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

    }else {

    final DonutProgress donutProgress = (DonutProgress) itemView.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress);


        donutProgress.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,0,0,0));

        donutProgress.setUnfinishedStrokeColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(Color.GRAY);
        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String newUrl = mResources[position].replaceAll(" ", "");



        imageLoader.displayImage(newUrl , imageView, defaultOptions,  new ImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("TAG","onLoadingCancelled");
                    }
        } , new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                        donutProgress.setMax(total);
                        donutProgress.setProgress(current);

                    }
                }
        );




    }

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);


}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

the above method is loading images by  the order of index ,  if imageView is at index 1 then it'll load before imageView at index 2

anyone can guide me how am gonna achieve the desired effect , it'll be so helpful for me

P.S. : if above stated information is not clear enough then please let me know i'll fix it  and i'm using [UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)